# Funciones con listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el sigiente programa con una funcion a la cual se le ha pasado dos listas como parametros. La función modifica la segunda lista sustituyendo cada elemento por una tupla en la que esté el elemento original acompañado del número de veces que aparece en la primera lista.

Para este caso, el input y el output de este ejercicio debería ser:

input = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 10, 12, 3, 14, 15] = [3, 8, 5]
output = [(3, 3), (8, 1), (5, 0)]

```
import func

lista1 = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 10, 12, 3, 14, 15]

lista2 = [4, 0, 5]

func.ejemplo(lista1, lista2)

print(cuenta_numeros)


def ejemplo(lista1, lista2):
 resultado=[]
 for i in lista2:
    resultado.append((i,lista1.count(i)))
 return resultado
```

El problema de dicho codigo es que su Output es: [4,0,5] y no como se muestra inicialmente. El primer archivo, no puede ser modificado dado que es el fichero main

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta Python-3.7? Ya has puesto la etiqueta Python-3.x, que es suficiente ya que esta cuestión en particular no necesita ninguna característica que esté sólo disponible en Python-3.7

Comment: Gracias por la orientación

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] y realiza tus preguntas en base  a este documento. Esta pregunta es duplicado de : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305699/secuenciador-con-listas-en-python

Answer (score 1):

El código que has escrito no está modificando la lista `lista2` que recibes como parámetro, sino que creas otra (`resultado`) y la retornas. La `lista2` no cambia en ningún momento.

Por otro lado, en tu "programa principal" se ve que tras llamar a la función hay un `print(cuenta_numeros)`, y resulta que `cuenta_numeros` no está definida por ningún sitio. ¿No será que tenías que hacer

```
cuenta_numeros = func.ejemplo(lista1, lista2)
```

para recoger el valor retornado por la función, en vez de intentar que cambie `lista2`?  Esto segundo, aunque puede hacerse, no es recomendable. Me extraña que te pidan una cosa así.

En todo caso se trataría de acceder a los elementos de `lista2` usando un índice, en vez del valor (o sea `lista2[0]`, `lista2[1]`, etc.. pero obviamente dentro de un bucle que fuera variando ese índice), y asignando de nuevo al mismo índice la tupla que estás calculando.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, efectivamente el archivo main está correcto tal cuál está